# Get child window location for the JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using JQuery UI dialog on my page and display contents of another page (page2.htm) in it. My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".hlk1").click(function () {
                var linkId = $(this).attr("linkID");

                // initialize dialog
                var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
                    height: 380,
                    width: 530,
                    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
                    buttons: {
                        "Done": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            // load content and open dialog
            dlg.load('page2.html?id=' + linkId).dialog('open');
        });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#" class="hlk1" linkid="305">Click here</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="hlk1" linkid="890">Click here</a>
<br/>
<div id="dialog"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On my page2.html I'd like to grab the QueryString from the URL to use on that page, but when I try to get location, I get the URL of the parent page using

```
this.location
```

My question is how do I get URL of the page2.html displayed in a div?

Here is my page2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <title>Page 2</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert(this.location);

        });

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="this.focus()">
    <div>       
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px;">

            <input type="text" id="PostId"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see the alert once page 2's content has loaded in the dialog?

Comment: yes, I see the alert and it is URL of the parent page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for jQuery's `.load()` function. You will see that `.load()` uses an ajax request to fetch the HTML from your `page2.html`, and then places it in your `#dialog` element.

The ajax call will not affect the `location` available from your browser, it basically just adds content to the current page. You will not be able to access any query parameters you pass in the URL via your call to `.load()`.

If you are attempting to put your `linkId` somewhere in your dialog box, the content of the dialog box will be readily available once the call to `.load()` is complete, and you can access it via jQuery selectors.

For example, if you wanted to populate the `<input type="text" id="PostId">` element with your `linkId`, you could just do `$('#PostId').val(linkId);` once your call to `.load()` has finished.

You can pass a callback function to `.load()` that will be called when the ajax request has completed and your content has been loaded to the page, so you could do whatever you want with the `linkId` in there, like this:

```
dlg.load('page2.html', function() {
    $('#PostId').val(linkId);
}).dialog('open');
```